# updating entrypoint with events

Tags: smartpy, upgrade

so I was trying to update an entry point with lazify=true.

```
import smartpy as sp


class testSC(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.update_initial_storage(
            x=sp.mutez(0))

    @sp.entry_point(lazify = False)
    def update_function(self, ep):
      sp.set_entry_point("f1", ep)

    @sp.entry_point(lazify = True)
    def f1(self):
        x = 5

    
@sp.add_test(name="TestSC")
def test():

    # deploy a contract
    c1 = testSC()
    sc = sp.test_scenario()
    sc += c1
    
    sc.h2("Update the contract")

    def f1(self, batch):
        x = 10
        sp.emit("event",tag="test")
        
    
    c1.update_function(sp.utils.wrap_entry_point("f1", f1))
```

I am trying to update the function f1 . But I am unable to upgrade the function as the new code of the function consists of event(I copied michelson code of the new f1() from smartpy and give it as a param in update_function() at better-call. But it says "Invalid primitive EMIT") . However if I remove the event code, then the f1 function is being upgraded.
so how can i update a function by adding event on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to better-call.dev.
Apperently it has not been updated yet to support the `EMIT.`

You can update your entrypoint using the SmartPy explorer: https://smartpy.io/explorer